# Getting -1 for one of my columns in SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Creating an app for seeing pets in the store, where I've created a database and a table called shelter.db and pets respectively. I've created a contract class to store all the constants related to the database, a class called PetDbHelper that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I have two activities CatalogActivity and EditorActivity. In CatalogActivity, I'm trying to read the table and here I tried to get the column indices of each column but the last column named 'weight' returns -1 which means as you may know 'no column exists' and in EditorActivity, I'm trying to insert pets in the table. I've checked everything but have no clue what's wrong with my code.

Here's the PetContract class:

```
package com.example.android.pets.data;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class PetsContract {

public static final class PetEntry implements BaseColumns {
    // CONSTANTS FOR TABLE AND COLUMN NAMES
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "pets";
    public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_PET_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PET_BREED = "breed";
    public static final String COLUMN_PET_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT = " weight";

    // CONSTANTS FOR GENDER
    public static final int GENDER_UNKNOWN = 0;
    public static final int GENDER_MALE = 1;
    public static final int GENDER_FEMALE = 2;
}
}
```

Here's the PetDbHelper that extends SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
package com.example.android.pets.data;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class PetDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "shelter.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public PetDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + PetsContract.PetEntry.TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + PetsContract.PetEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + PetsContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + PetsContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + " TEXT, "
            + PetsContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + PetsContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
}
}
```

Here's the code of CatalogActivity.java that is related to database:

```
/**
 * Displays list of pets that were entered and stored in the app.
 */
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PetDbHelper mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
 mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);

  private void displayDatabaseInfo() {
    // To access our database, we instantiate our subclass of 
SQLiteOpenHelper
    // and pass the context, which is the current activity.
    // CREATE AND/OR OPEN A DATABASE TO READ FROM IT
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

   // String[] projection = {PetEntry._ID, PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pets", null);
    TextView displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_pet);

    try {
        // Create a header in the Text View that looks like this:
        //
        // The pets table contains <number of rows in Cursor> pets.
        // _id - name - breed - gender - weight
        //
        // In the while loop below, iterate through the rows of the cursor and display
        // the information from each column in this order.
        displayView.setText("The pets table contains " + cursor.getColumnCount() + " pets.\n\n");
        displayView.append(PetEntry._ID + " - " +
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + " - " +
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + " - " +
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + " - " +
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT );

        // Figure out the index of each column
        int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry._ID);
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME);
        int breedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED);
        int genderColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER);
        int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "weight_index ?" + weightColumnIndex + "\n"
                + "id_index" + idColumnIndex + "\n"
                + "name_index" + nameColumnIndex + "\n"
                + "breed_index" + breedColumnIndex + "\n"
                + "gender_index" + genderColumnIndex , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } finally {
        // Always close the cursor when you're done reading from it. This releases all its
        // resources and makes it invalid.
        cursor.close();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    displayDatabaseInfo();
}
```

I know that's a lot of code, and here's the last piece of code of EditorActivity.java class: (excluded the code related to spinner object)

```
**
 * Allows user to create a new pet or edit an existing one.
 */
public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/** EditText field to enter the pet's name */
private EditText mNameEditText;

/** EditText field to enter the pet's breed */
private EditText mBreedEditText;

/** EditText field to enter the pet's weight */
private EditText mWeightEditText;

/** EditText field to enter the pet's gender */
private Spinner mGenderSpinner;

/**
 * Gender of the pet. The possible values are:
 * 0 for unknown gender, 1 for male, 2 for female.
 */
private int mGender = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

    // Find all relevant views that we will need to read user input from
    mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_name);
    mBreedEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_breed);
    mWeightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_weight);
    mGenderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);

}

private void addPet() {
    String name = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String breed = mBreedEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    int weight = Integer.parseInt(mWeightEditText.getText().toString().trim());

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PET_NAME, name);
    values.put(COLUMN_PET_BREED, breed);
    values.put(COLUMN_PET_GENDER, mGender);
    values.put(COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT, weight);

    PetDbHelper mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    if (result != -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pet saved with id: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving pet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_editor.xml file.
    // This adds menu items to the app bar.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_editor, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to a click on the "Save" menu option
        case R.id.action_save:
            // Save pet into the database
            addPet();
            // Exit the activity
            finish();
            return true;
        // Respond to a click on the "Delete" menu option
        case R.id.action_delete:
            // Do nothing for now
            return true;
        // Respond to a click on the "Up" arrow button in the app bar
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Navigate back to parent activity (CatalogActivity)
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: there is a blank space in `COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT = " weight"`, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks man for your help, next time I will write code with all my concentration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading whitespace is ignored in SQL but it matters in map keys - column names and their indices are essentially stored in a map you can access with `getColumnIndex()`.

```
public static final String COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT = " weight";
```

Remove the leading whitespace here.

Comment: Thank you for your help!